# Book with a boy and a girl and a magical world hidden in a wind up music box

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm looking for the title of a fairly recent book, probably written after 2000. In it, there is a boy who inherits an intricately painted music box with explicit instructions on how to safely use it, and his cousin, who immediately breaks those rules and exposes a hidden magical world and frees the Sorceress that was trapped inside. The kids have to defeat the Sorceress, or else....

Comment: No time traveling robots were harmed during the posting of this question.

Comment: Several bystanders received friction-burns due to the incredible speed of my response...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're referring to "[The Key to Rondo](http://www.chrlc.vic.gov.au/client/en_AU/chls/search/detailnonmodal/ent%3a%24002f%24002fSD_ILS%24002f1055%24002fSD_ILS:1055368/ada;jsessionid=EDF2B69280B8999A0A5F19B72C082377.enterprise-14800?qu=Children%27s%20stories.&rw=3900&ic=true&lm=CHRL-S&ps=300)" by Emily Rodda

> Turn the key three times only. Never turn the key while the music is
>   playing. Never pick up the box while the music is playing. Never close
>   the lid until the music has stopped. **The old music box, with its
>   strict rules,** has been carefully handed down through Leo's family for
>   hundreds of years. Painted scenes of villages, mysterious forests, a
>   castle on a hill and a queen in a long blue gown decorate its sides.
>   An astounding secret is hidden beneath its gleaming black lid. Now it
>   is Leo's music box, and **although he respects the rules, his least
>   favourite cousin, Mimi Langlander, does not.** When the rules are
>   broken, Leo's ordered life is changed forever as he and Mimi plunge
>   together into a thrilling quest in the fantastic world of Rondo.